# show popover above all elements jquery datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I am working on jquery data tables, The issue which I get is that bootstrap popover is hiding below the div, What I want is to show the popover above all elements when I click the action button. Attached image has all computed the code+ screenshot. I have already tried to add z-index to some other value but still, it is not working, Please have a look at it what is happening wrong, Thanks.

Here is the computed CSS (also attached in a screenshot)

```
.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
```

Image:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to check the "overflow" property of the tag around this table. If it has the value "hidden" that may be your problem.

Comment: There is not overflow property used, I have checked.

Comment: This is quite a correct observation but no solution is provided

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
$('your element').tooltip({ container: 'body' })
```

Comment: on which element?

Comment: $('.dropdown-menu').tooltip({ container: 'body' })

Answer (score 0):

As per @Devesh N's answer, try using your table's id instead:

`$('.dropdown-menu').tooltip({ container: '#tableId' });`